# How do I exclude hidden files and directories when using gsutil to rsync?

Tags: jekyll, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have a Jekyll blog with a directory structure that contains lots of hidden files and directories like `.DS_Store`, `.idea` and `.git`. It also has intermediate build artifacts and scripts that begin with `_` like `_deploy.sh` and `_drafts`.

I want to write a script that uploads everything to a bucket on Google Cloud Storage, except these hidden files and underscored artifacts.

I've tried using the `-x` flag, but my expressions either exclude the whole current directory, and upload nothing, or fail to exclude some of the content that I want to exclude.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
gsutil -m rsync -rx '\..*|./[.].*$|_*' ./ gs://my-bucket.com/path
```

And the output I'm observing:

```
$  ./_deployblog.sh
Building synchronization state...
Starting synchronization
```

Answer (score 4):

A series of really specific regular expressions solves the problem:

```
gsutil -m rsync -rdx '\..*|.*/\.[^/]*$|.*/\..*/.*$|_.*' . gs://my-bucket.com/path
```

Where the exclude pattern has 4 components separated by `|` characters.

```
\..*        <- excludes .files and .directories in the current directory
.*/\.[^/]*$ <- excludes .files in subdirectories
.*/\..*/.*$ <- excludes .directories in subdirectories
_.*         <- excludes _files and _directories
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `-x '(^|/)(_|\.)'`: we pick files when there is a beginning of path or a `/` followed by either `_` or `.`